# Exit virtual terminal

Tags: virtual-console

I'm using letest version on Ubuntu, I'm entered Virtual Terminal how to I exit. Some body says press ctrl+alt+7 or ctrl+alt+8 but its worked as same what can i do. I have important details on my mechine [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxfvX.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

To return from a virtual console to your graphical session on TTY2, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. If you did not yet log in on your desktop, then hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. This will bring you to the login manager on TTY1.

While in a text console (TTY3 and higher), you can move to the next or the previous with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right</kbd>.

Comment: No it doesn't work

Comment: It works like that normally.

Comment: Its return to virtual Terminal again & again its not  work Normally as .. I tried so many this but it's not working please have any methods?

Comment: How do you enter virtual terminal? Perhaps also, why? See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console